# Javascript if active element's value equals add class

Tags: javascript

I had to create an element drag and drop function, that all went smooth, now I need to change CSS based on the element dropped.

JS:

```
$(function (md) {
    $("li").draggable();
    $("div").droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            if (confirm('Vai esat pārliecināts?')) {
                if($(ui.draggable).value == "darzenis") {
                    $( "ul li:nth-child(even)" ) .addClass('darzenis');
                }
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
            }
    }
});

$( "ul li:nth-child(even)" ) .addClass('ui-state-default');
$( "ul li:nth-child(odd)" ) .addClass('ui-state-highlight');});
```

HTML:

```
<li value="darzenis">Buljonāās</li>
```

My question is how do I check if the value of the dropped element equals a specific string? (Line 6)

Comment: Where does the value come from? It is the text of the list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `attr` method to get attribute value

replace

```
if($(ui.draggable).value == "darzenis") {
```

with

```
if($(ui.draggable).attr("value") == "darzenis") {
```

`$(ui.draggable)` is a jquery object not DOM object, its `value` property may not reflect its attribute value. Use `attr()` method to get attribute value.